# Geometry of log-concave density functions and its distribution

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, convex-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is log concave (density function). Consider now the antiderivative (distribution function) $F(t)=\int_{{ x\le t}}f(x)dx$, which is also log concave. We know that for each component this, say $F_1(\cdot,t_2,\cdots,t_n)$ has regions of concavity and convexity. I was wondering if this result can be extended in the sense that for each point $(t_1,\cdots,t_n)$, either the function $F$ is concave on $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n|x\ge t\}$ or convex on $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n|x\le t\}$.

Thanks a bunch in advance for your input.

Comment: What is the meaning of $x\le t$ when both $x$ and $t$ are vectors?

Comment: @LeonidKovalev Sorry - I meant for each $i\in {1,...n}$ $x_i\le t_i$. Do you have any suggestions? If this is not the case, is there some more restricted set, say I restrict $x_i < x_j$ for $i< j$. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general. Consider the case where $f$ is the density of a standard 2D Gaussian. Let $\Phi$ be the Gaussian CDF. Then, $F(x, y) = \Phi(x)\Phi(y)$, and some straightforward computations show that at $(0, 0)$ the Hessian of $F$ is indefinite, so it will be neither concave nor convex near there.